Where to find WINAPI for Windows health indices?
Due to some weird WiFi problems, I've developed a background app to keep WiFi busy and report disturbances in the EventLog.
//****        Ping router      ****************

char replay[128] = { 0 };
LPVOID replayBuf = (LPVOID)replay;
char requestData[] = "Send data";
unsigned long ipAddr = inet_addr(ip);
int noOffailures = 0;

// This function is called at the timer ticks 
// UINT_PTR ret = SetTimer(NULL, 0, period, (TIMERPROC)Ping);
// through the message loop, where the arguments get defined

void CALLBACK Ping(HWND hWnd, UINT message, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    DWORD dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho2(hIcmpFile, /*event*/ NULL, /*callB*/ NULL, /*ctx*/ NULL,
        ipAddr, requestData, sizeof(requestData), /*optns*/ NULL,
        replayBuf, /*repSiz*/ 128, /*timeout ms*/ 1000);

    if (dwRetVal == 0) Failure();   // ICMP call failed
    else
    {
        PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY)replayBuf;
        if (pEchoReply->Status != 0) Failure();     // ICMP sent but no echo
        else if (noOffailures != 0)                 // Report success after failures
        {
            Log(true, noOffailures);
            noOffailures = 0;
        }
    }
}

Now and then, I see that WiFi goes down and recovers shortly after some to some tens of seconds just to go down again. The disturbance continues for 2–6 minutes and disappears. Other devices on the same WiFi network show no disturbances. The disturbance may happen while the PC stays unused. I have the OEM's latest WiFi driver.
I would like to pick some health indices when WiFi goes down, e.g., the CPU temperature. Where can I find the Win32 API for such functions?
I'm using an Acer Aspire A515-43 with Windows 11.
What else can I do to understand and remedy the PC's malfunction?

I afraid there is no such API. You have to call to hardware/BIOS directly as CPU-Z does.

With the exception of the final two paragraphs none of the text posted here is relevant to the question. As for the question you didn't ask the solution is to use the Network List Manager. It supports setting up a callback that's called whenever network connectivity changes. This is more reliable and far less intrusive than constantly trying to ping some host.

@IInspectable: Hi IInspectable, Formally, you may be right. However, it does have value to describe the problem. You may get another help from somebody who knows the problem. Actually, I want to solve a problem rather than measure the CPU temperature. I'll have a look at the Network List Manager. But my problem is not to choose a network; my network is fine. My PC is unstable, and I'd like to understand why.

@Mike Petrichenko: Thank you. However, the small app Core Temp shows the CPU temperature on my several PCs, all different. Task manager can show load on any PC. There must be some standardized API for these properties.

As far as I know, this information doesn't have an API of its own, instead it's presented through WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation),. Take a look at the cim_temperature_sensor class, for example.
